# Quarkus to load 3rd party properties file from classpath

Tags: openid, quarkus

I'm using a 3rd party library (`org.expressme.JOpenId:1.08`) that loads some properties file during init:

```
input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("openid-providers.properties");
```

Native compilation works, but the app throws an exception at runtime:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null
2021-07-29T18:35:18.827799150Z at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:246)
2021-07-29T18:35:18.827805500Z at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:406)
2021-07-29T18:35:18.827809990Z at org.expressme.openid.ShortName.<init>(ShortName.java:27)
2021-07-29T18:35:18.827814580Z at org.expressme.openid.OpenIdManager.<init>(OpenIdManager.java:28)
```

How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make GraalVM aware of that resource.
As mentioned [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#including-resources), you can add something like:

```
quarkus.native.resources.includes=openid-providers.properties
```

in your `application.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried by changing the "application.properties" to "/application.properties" or "classpath:path/application.propeties? As sometime maven fails to locate file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's 3rd party lib.